# CSS height and inline height attribute disobeyed me

Tags: jquery, css, height

I have a problem with the height of the container div. I want
 it to be 100% of the body   but does't work.
I added css body height=100%

```js
var d = document;
$(d).ready(function () {
    $("#con").append($("<div id='d'></div>").css({
        'height':' 50px',
        'width': '100px',
        'background': 'lightgreen',
        'borderRadius':'5px',
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':'100px',
        'top' :'100px'
        
    })).on("mousemove",function(e){
    var x = e.pageX-$("#con").offset().left;
    var y = e.pageY-$("#con").offset().top;
        $("#d").html(x+" "+y);
    });
    
});
```

```css
/*edit*/ 
body ,html {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;}
/*endof edit*/
#con{
    border:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;/*not working as expected*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con" height="100%"></div>
<!-- height attribut above and css height dont ant to take

effect-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make the `%` value on height works you need A reference value, fixed value on the parents as well ... set `100%` for html and body tags too:

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}
```

```js
var d = document;
$(d).ready(function () {
    $("#con").append($("<div id='d'></div>").css({
        'height':' 50px',
        'width': '100px',
        'background': 'lightgreen',
        'borderRadius':'5px',
        'position':'absolute',
        'left':'100px',
        'top' :'100px'
        
    })).on("mousemove",function(e){
    var x = e.pageX-$("#con").offset().left;
    var y = e.pageY-$("#con").offset().top;
        $("#d").html(x+" "+y);
    });
    
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
}
#con{
    background:black;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;/*not working as expected*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="con" height="100%"></div>
<!-- height attribut above and css height dont ant to take

effect-->
```

Comment: I voted up and checked it it's our turn to vote up ;(